# Create line after text with css

Tags: css

Im trying to make a line after each of my h2 tags. I can´t figure out how I should tell the width, cause the lenght of the h2 headlines is differ from h2 to h2.

I use the :after method to create lines

```
       h2:after {
       position: absolute;
       content: "";
       height: 2px;
       background-color: #242424;
       width: 50%;
       margin-left: 15px;
       top: 50%;
       }
```

Check code here: http://jsfiddle.net/s9gHf/
As you can see the line get too wide, and make the website too wide.

Comment: how about you remove the `background-color`, `width`, `top` and enter in `content` the line as long as you want to be using underscore `__` http://jsfiddle.net/3dj8m/ , or do you want the width to respond based on the h2 element width ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You could achieve this with an extra `<span>`:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

h2 span {
  background-color: white;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Featured products</span></h2>
<h2><span>Here is a very long h2, and as you can see the line get too wide</span></h2>
```

Another solution without the extra `<span>` but requires an `overflow: hidden` on the `<h2>`:

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0.5em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h2><span>Featured products</span></h2>
<h2><span>Here is a very long h2, and as you can see the line get too wide</span></h2>
```

External examples: [First](http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/pkm5r/), [Second](http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/h2JRj/)

Comment: Thank you... That overflow:hidden, did it all!

Comment: overflow:hidden perfect for colored background!

Answer (score 34):

There's no need for extra wrappers or span elements anymore. Flexbox and Grid can handle this easily.

```css
h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h2::after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h2>Heading</h2>
```

Comment: This solution is great! The CSS is simple and there is no need to add any extra elements in HTML.

Answer (score 9):

using flexbox:

```css
h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h2 span {
  content: "";
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title <span></span></h2>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another, in my opinion even simpler solution using a flex wrapper:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Text</p>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

[External link](https://jsfiddle.net/mxef25m3/2/)

Answer (score 3):

I notice that there are some flexbox implementations but they don't explain why and how to use it.

##### First, we just need one element, for this example `h2`.

- We will change the element's display behavior to `display: flex`
- Then, we center vertically its child elements using `align-items: center`.

```css
h2 {
    ...
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

##### Then, let's draw the line using the pseudo-element `after`.

- We add `''` to the `content` property to draw the element (we must).
- Now lets make it flexible using `flex: auto`. This means that our element is sized according to its width and height properties. It grows to absorb any extra free space in the flex container, and shrinks to its minimum size to fit the container. This is equivalent to setting `flex: 1 1 auto`.
- Then we add an small gap between the text and the line using `margin-left: 1rem`.
- Finally, we draw a black line using `border-top: 1px solid #000`.

```css
h2::after {
    content: '';
    flex: auto;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

##### Here is functional snippet.

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 1em; /* not needed */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

h2::after {
  content: '';
  flex: auto;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h2>Normal title</h2>
<h2>Very long title to test the behavior of the element when the content is wider</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most easy way I found to achieve the result: Just use hr tag before the text, and set the margin top for text. Very short and easy to understand! [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raftytk/73f49u0s/11/)

```css
h2 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: -22px;
  width: 25%;
}

hr {
  border: 1px solid #e9a216;
}
```

```html
<br>

<hr>
<h2>ABOUT US</h2>
```

Comment: The <hr> tag now has a semantic meaning and shouldn't be use as a graphic only element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr). This would be like using <h1> only to make text bigger. It's not what it is for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zz7Wq/2/

I use a background instead of after and use my H1 or H2 to cover the background. Not quite your method above but does work well for me.

CSS

```
.title-box { background: #fff url('images/bar-orange.jpg') repeat-x left; text-align: left; margin-bottom: 20px;}
.title-box h1 { color: #000; background-color: #fff; display: inline; padding: 0 50px 0 50px; }
```

HTML

```
<div class="title-box"><h1>Title can go here</h1></div>
<div class="title-box"><h1>Title can go here this one is really really long</h1></div>
```

Comment: @user3026212 I looked at the site and you have some bad html in there, around line 199-200. You have an open style=". Also can you post the code / how you integrated it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced at all so feel free to correct things. However, I tried all these answers, but always had a problem in some screen.
So I tried the following that worked for me and looks as I want it in almost all screens with the exception of mobile.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div id="Section-Title">
     <div id="h2"> YOUR TITLE
        <div id="line"><hr></div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
background:#fff;
max-width:100%;
margin:20px auto;
padding:50px 5%;}

#Section-Title{
margin: 2% auto;
width:98%;
overflow: hidden;}

#h2{
float:left;
width:100%;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:1.5vw;}

#h2 #line {
display:inline-block;
float:right;
margin:auto;
margin-left:10px;
width:90%;
position:absolute;
top:-5%;}

#Section-Title:after{content:""; display:block; clear:both; }
.wrapper:after{content:""; display:block; clear:both; }
```