# Getting a line through the a tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a line through the `a` tag for decorative effect. The line should span the entire width but not go through content of the tag itself.

This is what I want,

[image]

This is what I've got so far.

```css
a {
  background: none;
}

a::after {
  content: "";
  border: 3px solid #000;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -50%;
}
```

```html
<a class="fw-bold" href="">Explore Services</a>
```

And here is the jsfiddle of the above code https://jsfiddle.net/68fkvhcw/

Why is the position relative with negative top margin not working?

Comment: Note about possible indicated duplicate: The question here asks for a link where the whole line/element acts as a link/is clickable. This is not covered by the previously indicated duplicate.

Comment: @Johannes this one for the duplicate cover it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57891231/8620333 (you make the h2 a link and it's done)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a possible way to do that. Wrap the `a` tag all around the elements, make that a flex container and use settings similar to those of my snippet below:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

a.link1:link,
a.link1:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: green;
}

.link1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #dfd;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

.text1 {
  flex-grow: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.line {
  height: 2px;
  background: #fa0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<a class="link1" href="#">
  <div class="text1">Explore all Services</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a code snippet as you want. But here is a suggestion that doesn't use styles directly on `<a>` tag else it will affect all your `<a>` tags on the page. So I have defined a style here `.my_underline`

You can adjust the thickness of the line and the color of the font.

```css
 .my_underline {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:aqua;
}

 .my_underline:after {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a class="fw-bold my_underline" href="">Explore all Services</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use theses styles ,

```css
a {
color: #000000;
font-family: 'collegeregular';
font-size: 20px;
margin-left: 5px;
position: relative;
width: 93%;
}

a::after {
position: absolute;
content: "";
height: 2px;
background-color: #242424;
width: 50%;
margin-left: 15px;
top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a class="fw-bold" href="">Explore Services</a>
```

Comment: Hello @ShivaKrishna, I have created a snippet from your code and ran it. The result does not match the desired output. Maybe I have missed something? Anyway, you might want to re-check the CSS.